# Proof for the universal property of the tensor product of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

The following is the theorem regarding the universal property of tensor products of modules in Dummit and Foote:

> Let $R$ be a subring of $S$, let $N$ be a left $R$-module and $\iota:N\to S\otimes_RN$ be the $R$-module homomorphism defined by $\iota(n)=1\otimes n$. Suppose that $L$ is any left $S$-module (hence also an $R$-module) and that $\varphi:N\to L$ is an $R$-module homomorphism from $N$ to $L$. Then there is a unique $S$-module homomorphism $\Phi:S\otimes_RN\to L$ such that $\varphi$ factors through $\Phi$, i.e., $\varphi=\Phi\circ\iota$ and the diagram
>   [image]
>
> commutes. Coversely, if $\Phi: S\otimes_RN\to L$ is an $S$-module homomorphism then $\varphi=\Phi\circ\iota$ is an $R$-module homomorphism from $N$ to $L$.

The proof goes as follows

- Define $\psi:S\times N\to L$ with $\psi(s,n)=s\varphi(n)$.
- By the universal property of free $\mathbf{Z}$-module on the set $S\times N$, denoted as $F(S\times N)$, there exists a $\mathbf{Z}$-module homomorphism $\Psi:F(S\times N)\to L$ such that $\Psi(s,n)=\psi(s,n)=s\phi(n)$.
- Since $\varphi$ is an $R$-module homomorphism, the generators of the subgroup $H$ <s>in the following equations</s> all map to zero in $L$, where the generators are given by elements of the form
  $$
  (x+y,n)-(x,n)-(y,n),\quad (x,m+n)-(x,m)-(x,n),\quad (sr,n)-(s,rn),\\
  x,y\in S,\,m,n\in N,\, r\in R.
  $$
- $\color{blue}{\textrm{Hence}}$, $\Psi$ factors through $H$, i.e., there is a well defined $\mathbf{Z}$-module homomorphism $\Phi$ from $F/H=S\otimes_RN$ to $L$ satisfying $\Phi(s\otimes n)=s\varphi(n)$.
- The rest of the proof can be read below.

Here is my **question**:

> Could anyone elaborate how the "Hence" step is implied by the third bullet point, from which I can only see that $H\subset \ker\Psi$?

---

Here is the original proof in the book:
[image]

Comment: What is $H$? $\,$

Comment: @D_S: It is the subgroup generated by "the following equations".

Comment: @Jack, equations cannot generate a subgroup.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Thanks for your comment. I have edited the post according to what is originally in the book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$H \subseteq \textrm{ker } \Psi$ is all you need for $\Psi$ to factor through the quotient $F/H$.

In general, let $\delta: A \rightarrow B$ be a homomorphism of abelian groups ($\mathbf Z$-modules, same thing), and let $A_0$ be a subgroup of $A$.  To say that $\delta$ **factors through** $A_0$ (or $A/A_0$) is to say that there exists an abelian group homomorphism $\bar{\delta}: A/A_0 \rightarrow B$ such that $\bar{\delta}(a + A_0) = \delta(a)$ for all $a \in A$.

If such a homomorphism exists, it is clearly unique.  The only issue barring the existence of such a homomorphism is the possibility that it is not well defined.  And you can check that it *is* well defined if and only if $A_0$ is contained in the kernel of $\delta$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would be interested in seeing a reference for the "factor through" theorem.

Comment: I think every abstract algebra textbook should have some version of it.  But it is easy to prove yourself: to say that $\bar{\delta}$ is well defined is to say that if $a + A_0 = a' + A_0$ (that is, $a - a' \in A_0$), then $\delta(a) = \delta(a')$.

Comment: Hmm, it looks very much similar to the first isomorphism theorem. Maybe it is called the universal property of quotient groups.

Comment: It is easy to check that if $\bar{\delta}$ is well defined (that is, $A_0 \subseteq \textrm{ker } \delta$), then $\textrm{ker } \bar{\delta} = \textrm{ker } \delta/A_0$ (the image of $\textrm{ker } \delta$ under the homomorphism $A \rightarrow A/A_0$).  The first isomorphism theorem is a special case of this, when $A_0 = \textrm{ker } \delta$.  Here the kernel of $\bar{\delta}$ is $\textrm{ker } \delta/\textrm{ker } \delta$, which is the trivial subgroup of $A/\textrm{ker } \delta$.  Thus $\bar{\delta}$ is injective in this case (and an isomorphism if and only if $\delta$ is surjective).

Answer (score 0):

On page 100 of Dummit and Foote, there is a remark about the "universal property" of quotient groups, which explains the "Hence" step (in particular it explains what "factors through" means).

One can also read this note: 
https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-703-modern-algebra-spring-2013/lecture-notes/MIT18_703S13_pra_l_9.pdf